# How to get SharePoint user alerts for a site collection[Include all sub-sites] using client object Model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to get all user alerts[Under Site setting] for all the sub-sites under site collection using client object model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint Online, you can get user alerts like this:

```
        string userName = "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
        string password = "xx";
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx"))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
            Web web = clientContext.Web;

                var siteUsersColl = from user in web.SiteUsers
                                    where user.PrincipalType == Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.User
                                    select user;
                var usersResult = clientContext.LoadQuery(siteUsersColl);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                int count = 0;
                foreach (var user in siteUsersColl)
                {
                    //ensure that user is present
                    var curruser = web.EnsureUser(user.LoginName);

                    //load the users alerts, available after jan 2017 CSOM update in SPO, not sure about OnPrem
                    var alerts = user.Alerts;
                    context.Load(alerts);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (Alert alert in alerts)
                    {
                        //get the alert
                        var type = alert.Title;
                    }

                    count += alerts.Count;
                }
       }
```

The alerts object is available for SharePoint Online from Jan. 2017:

[New SharePoint CSOM version released for SharePoint Online – January 2017](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-january-2017/)

Comment: I am using sharepoint on premise , in that  context.Load(alerts) is getting failed. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/09d6de5f-6cfe-4fd1-81ca-825143acd09c/how-to-get-all-sharepoint-user-alerts-for-a-sitecollection-using-powershell?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious